# JAVA - Why won't my while loop stop when I enter in filter or sort to leave it?

Tags: java

```
while((!(command.toLowerCase().contains("filter")==true) || 
       !(command.toLowerCase().contains("sort")==true))){
    System.out.println("Input is invalid. Please try again.");
    command = range.nextLine();    
}
```

Comment: Say your `while` condition in words, out loud.

Comment: Lets make it simpler. What value `x` doesn't pass this test `(x!=1 or x!=2)`?

Comment: I tried that and when I do it returns true, so shouldn't it leave the while loop?

Comment: If a `while` condition returns `true`, does it stop?

Comment: These are the questions you should be asking yourself.

Comment: Pshemo - any number, but 1 or 2 I believe
Sotirios - That's what I'm pretty sure it's suppose to do

Comment: Put it on paper and calculate to be sure. Maybe you will discover something.

Comment: BTW, it's silly to do `==true` on a boolean value.  It just gives you the same value you already had.

Comment: Or NVM. Lets test `(x!=1 or x!=2)` for `x=1`. `(x!=1 or x!=2)` == `(1!=1 or 1!=2)` == `(false or true)` == .... wait for it.... `TRUE` (because we are using OR here) so this condition doesn't eliminate `x=1` (in fact it doesn't eliminate any number).

Answer (score 2):

You're checking using `||` and one of your statements will always be true. Try `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition can be rewritten as this :

```
(((command.toLowerCase().contains("filter")==false) || 
(command.toLowerCase().contains("sort")==false)))
```

So it means, in human language, while command does not contain filer OR command does not containt sort, then keep looping. Therefore if you type only one of them, the second condition is true and the whole statement is true. For what you have, if you write string, which contains both of them, then it ends, for example : "filter is sorted".

If you want to end with type only one of that word, you have to use AND, which is &&, resuling in :

```
(((command.toLowerCase().contains("filter")==false) && 
(command.toLowerCase().contains("sort")==false)))
```

Comment: I just tried this. It breaks the while loop when I enter in filter, but it doesn't even go into the while loop when I enter in sort.

Comment: Oh and by the way I used the && statement

Comment: @KevinNguyen - of course it does not go INTO the while loop, if you write either filter or sort. What exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If your command must contain either "filter" or "sort". Then the following boolean expression satisfy that.

```
command.toLowerCase().contains("filter") || command.toLowerCase().contains("sort")
```

Now if I understand you correctly, you want to keep looking for a command while the above condition is NOT met.

```
while( !(command.toLowerCase().contains("filter") || command.toLowerCase().contains("sort")) )
```

The above while condition says "while NOT (filter or sort) keep looping"